# Split a txt file after every 4 lines

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Looking for a batch file to split a txt file after every 4 lines.
New files should have their respective first line as the file name.

Comment: It is a bit weird to have the whole question in the title and the repeated question in the body, I'd suggest to edit.

Comment: I agree, @BrunoLevy, there should be stated what have been tried so far, and perhaps also a sample text file; in addition, @Pankan should clarify whether the question is _really_ about **MS-DOS**, or if it is the **Windows** command prompt `cmd`, because these are _different_ things...

Comment: I am sorry guys I am new here and couldn't really go through all the forum rules before posting. It's for a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET /a splitat=4
SET /a lineno=%splitat%
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q33598527.txt) DO (
 IF !lineno!==%splitat% SET "destfile=%%a"
 >>"%destdir%\!destfile!" ECHO(%%a
 SET /a lineno-=1
 IF !lineno!==0 SET /a lineno=%splitat%
)
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `destedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q33598527.txt` containing sample data for my testing.

Simply - read each line and count down from the maximum. reset the counter to maximum if it reaches 0. set the destination filename to the line contents if the counter is maximum (which will be the first line of the group)

This uses delayed-expansion (`!varname!`) to access the changing values of the variables within the loop.